# How to filter results from a table with PDO Statement

Tags: php, mysql

I do have a PDO Statement here and I want to filter the result using buttons or radio button or dropdown,

```
<tbody>
                            <?php
                                $conn = $pdo->open();

                                try{
                                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM sales WHERE user_id=:user_id ORDER BY sales_date DESC");
                                    $stmt->execute(['user_id'=>$user['id']]);
                                    foreach($stmt as $row){
                                        $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM details LEFT JOIN products ON products.id=details.product_id WHERE sales_id=:id");
                                        $stmt2->execute(['id'=>$row['id']]);
                                        $total = 0;
                                        foreach($stmt2 as $row2){
                                            $subtotal = $row2['price']*$row2['quantity'];
                                            $total += $subtotal;
                                        }
                                        echo "<input type=button id=>"


                                        echo "
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class='hidden'></td>
                                                <td>".date('M d, Y', strtotime($row['sales_date']))."</td>
                                                <td>".$row['transType']."</td>
                                                <td>".$row['pay_id']."</td>
                                                <td>&#8369; ".$row['vAmount']."</td>
                                                <td>".$row['eStatus']."</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        ";
                                    }

                                }
                                catch(PDOException $e){
                                    echo "There is some problem in connection: " . $e->getMessage();
                                }

                                $pdo->close();
                            ?>
                            </tbody>
```

The problem is how can I filter the results using the transtype? I already prepared a button at the top but I seems lost with what I am doing. Please somebody enlighten me. Thank you! The list of the transtype was in enum w/c is Investment, Deposit and Withdrawal.

Comment: Is there a list of all possible transtype values in your database which you can put into a dropdown? Or do you want the user to be able to type any value and search for it? Be more specific about the requirements please. Beyond that you'll need a HTML form and then some PHP code to read if the value has been submitted or not and then adjust the SQL query accordingly. If you're not familiar with HTML forms etc then please study some introductory tutorials...the general principle of this is not a new problem and something you can study easily. It's not clear _precisely_ where you're stuck.

Comment: What do you mean by "using the transtype"? What is that? Also, as long as this question is not **really** related to HTML or [tag:forms], please remove these tags

Comment: @NicoHaase I havent clicked that forms and html. It just automatically tagged.

Comment: @ADyson only 3 transtype values. It is in enum. I'll add in the description sorry for that.

Comment: If I right the [DataTables with filter](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) and [server side processing](https://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html) is useful for your case.